# What does queueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier do in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, reusability

I am working with open source iOs app and came across this:

queueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

How do you use this? I kind of think I may have an idea of it - perhaps it is a variable that is passed through multiple times? Do you use it each time? I'm a beginner, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Think about all the cell of a table view exists in an array of cells.

Once the table view wants to load a cell it calls this method with the indexPath (to insert it into the right index) and identifier to recognise the cell (if you have multiple cells)

Now, if the this method return nil. Then the "array of cells" does not contains a cell that can be reused, and the a cell needs to be initialised.

This method if for performance issues mainly, so you will not have to instantiate a instance of a cell every time you want to load a cell.